# Why won't "repeat" in GNU prolog work as expected?

Tags: prolog

I try to run the following code in my GNU 1.4.5 .

The file name is other.pl
I run it by : `[other].` I run function by `test.`

Then I enter some number and press enter. It goes on to the next line to enter the number again, without writing "Please enter a number".

Im confused why prolog won't execute repeat properly.

Demonstration:

```
|?-  test.
Please enter a number1
42
3
   ...(keeps allowing me to enter nums)
```

Code:

```
 test :- repeat, 
                     write('Please enter a number'), 
                     read(X), 
                     (X=:=42).
```

Answer (score 3):

The standard `read/1` predicate reads a Prolog term, which is expected to end with a period (`.`). For example:

```
| ?- test.
Please enter a number3.
Please enter a number42.

true ?
```

Also, notice above when we input the expected number, GNU Prolog is asking if we want it to look for alternative proofs by displaying `true ?`. That happens due to the choice-point created by each call to `repeat/0`. When using `repeat/0` based loops, you should always add a cut after the test. Style-wise, it's also recommended that you indent the body of the loop. In this case:

```
test :-
    repeat, 
        write('Please enter a number'), 
        read(X),
    X =:= 42,
    !.
```